# Collision detection for player

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, pong

My code works like pong except I tried to make it 4 players. Collision between the ball and the player sort of works but it only goes towards one direction. I want to make it so that if the ball hits the top edge of the player the ball goes up and if it hit's the side of the player, the ball goes flying to that direction. Right now the ball only goes in a diagonal direction.

```
import turtle
import math

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("PMH HANDBALL")
wn.bgcolor("Black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()- 
t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
    if distance < 50:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Handball court top right
court = turtle.Turtle()
court.speed(0)
court.color("white")
court.hideturtle()
court.goto(400, 0)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)

#handball court top left
court.speed(0)
court.color("white")
court.hideturtle()
court.goto(-400, 0)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)

#Handball court bottom left
court.speed(0)
court.color("white")
court.hideturtle()
court.goto(-400, -400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)

#handball court bottom right
court.speed(0)
court.color("white")
court.hideturtle()
court.goto(0, -400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)
court.left(90)
court.forward(400)



#handball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("square")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(50, 50)
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = -2


#player 1
player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.speed(0)
player1.shape("square")
player1.color("red")
player1.shapesize(stretch_wid=4, stretch_len=4)
player1.penup()
player1.goto(100, 200)

#player 2
player2 = turtle.Turtle()
player2.speed(0)
player2.shape("square")
player2.color("yellow")
player2.shapesize(stretch_wid=4, stretch_len=4)
player2.penup()
player2.goto(100, -200)

#player 3
player3 = turtle.Turtle()
player3.speed(0)
player3.shape("square")
player3.color("green")
player3.shapesize(stretch_wid=4, stretch_len=4)
player3.penup()
player3.goto(-100, 200)

#player 4
player4 = turtle.Turtle()
player4.speed(0)
player4.shape("square")
player4.color("blue")
player4.shapesize(stretch_wid=4, stretch_len=4)
player4.penup()
player4.goto(-100, -200)


#function
def player1_up():
    y = player1.ycor()
    y += 20
    player1.sety(y)

    x = player1.xcor()
    x += 20

def player1_down():
    y = player1.ycor()
    y -= 20
    player1.sety(y)

def player1_right():
    x = player1.xcor()
    x += 20
    player1.setx(x)

def player1_left():
    x = player1.xcor()
    x -= 20
    player1.setx(x)

def player2_up():
    y = player2.ycor()
    y += 20
    player2.sety(y)

def player2_down():
    y = player2.ycor()
    y -= 20
    player2.sety(y)

def player2_right():
    x = player2.xcor()
    x += 20
    player2.setx(x)

def player2_left():
    x = player2.xcor()
    x += -20
    player2.setx(x)

def player3_up():
    y = player3.ycor()
    y += 20
    player3.sety(y)

    x = player1.xcor()
    x += 20

def player3_down():
    y = player3.ycor()
    y -= 20
    player3.sety(y)

def player3_right():
    x = player3.xcor()
    x += 20
    player3.setx(x)

def player3_left():
     x = player3.xcor()
     x -= 20
     player3.setx(x)

def player4_up():
    y = player4.ycor()
    y += 20
    player4.sety(y)

    x = player4.xcor()
    x += 20

def player4_down():
    y = player4.ycor()
    y -= 20
    player4.sety(y)

def player4_right():
    x = player4.xcor()
    x += 20
    player4.setx(x)

def player4_left():
     x = player4.xcor()
     x -= 20
     player4.setx(x)

#keyboard bind
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(player1_up, "i")
wn.onkeypress(player1_down, "k")
wn.onkeypress(player1_right, "l")
wn.onkeypress(player1_left, "j")

wn.onkeypress(player2_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(player2_down, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(player2_right, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(player2_left, "Left")

wn.onkeypress(player3_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(player3_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(player3_right, "d")
wn.onkeypress(player3_left, "a")

wn.onkeypress(player4_up, "t")
wn.onkeypress(player4_down, "g")
wn.onkeypress(player4_right, "h")
wn.onkeypress(player4_left, "f")





#main loop that keeps window running
while True:
    wn.update()


    #boundary checking topright
    if player1.xcor() > 360:
        player1.goto(360, player1.ycor())

    if player1.xcor() < 25:
        player1.goto(40, player1.ycor())

    if player1.ycor() > 360:
        player1.goto(player1.xcor(), 360)

    if player1.ycor() < 35:
        player1.goto(player1.xcor(), 40)

#Boundary checking bottomright
    if player2.xcor() > 360:
        player2.goto(360, player2.ycor())

    if player2.xcor() < 25:
        player2.goto(40, player2.ycor())

    if player2.ycor() > -40:
        player2.goto(player2.xcor(), -40)

    if player2.ycor() < -360:
        player2.goto(player2.xcor(), -360)

#boundary checking topleft
    if player3.xcor() > -40:
        player3.goto(-40, player3.ycor())

    if player3.xcor() < -360:
        player3.goto(-360, player3.ycor())

    if player3.ycor() > 360:
        player3.goto(player3.xcor(), 360)

    if player3.ycor() < 35:
        player3.goto(player3.xcor(), 40)

#boundary checking bottomleft
    if player4.xcor() > -40:
        player4.goto(-40, player4.ycor())

    if player4.xcor() < -360:
        player4.goto(-360, player4.ycor())

    if player4.ycor() > -40:
    player4.goto(player4.xcor(), -40)

    if player4.ycor() < -360:
        player4.goto(player4.xcor(), -360)


#ball movement
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    #border checking for ball

    if ball.ycor() > 420:
        ball.goto(50,50)
        ball.dy *= -1


    if ball.ycor() < -420:
        ball.goto(50,50)
        ball.dy *= 1

    if ball.xcor() > 420:
        ball.goto(50, 50)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if ball.xcor() < -420:
        ball.goto(50, 50)
        ball.dx *= -1


    #player and ball collisons
    if isCollision(ball, player4):
        ball.dy *= -1
        ball.dx *= -1

    if isCollision(ball, player3):
        ball.dy *= -1
        ball.dx *= -1

    if isCollision(ball, player2):
        ball.dy *= -1
        ball.dx *= -1

    if isCollision(ball, player1):
        ball.dy *= -1
        ball.dx *= -1
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate the question. It will be helpful for the person answering it :)

Comment: When the ball hits the player, it only goes in one direction, I want to make it so that if the ball hits the top edge of the player the ball goes up and if it hit's the side of the player, the ball goes flying to that direction. Right now the ball only goes in a diagonal direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked the ball with player collision logic in your code to provide a simple, but playable bounce motion:

[image]

Far from perfect, this should give you a starting point from which to experiment.  I've also rewritten your code to simplify extending it -- it's about half the size and paramerterized to the size of the screen and players:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial
from random import choice

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
PLAYER_SIZE = 80

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    return t1.distance(t2) < (PLAYER_SIZE + CURSOR_SIZE) / 2

# Event handlers
def player_up(player):
    player.sety(player.ycor() + 20)

def player_down(player):
    player.sety(player.ycor() - 20)

def player_right(player):
    player.setx(player.xcor() + 20)

def player_left(player):
    player.setx(player.xcor() - 20)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("PMH HANDBALL")
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(0)

# Handball court

court = Turtle()
court.hideturtle()
court.color('white')
court.width(4)

for x, y in ((0, -HEIGHT/2), (-WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/2), (-WIDTH/2, 0), (0, 0)):
    court.goto(x, y)
    for _ in range(2):
        court.forward(WIDTH/2)
        court.left(90)
        court.forward(HEIGHT/2)
        court.left(90)

# Handball
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('white')

ball.penup()

ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2
ball.dx *= choice([-1, 1])
ball.dy *= choice([-1, 1])

# Player 1
player1 = Turtle()
player1.shape('square')
player1.color('red')
player1.shapesize(PLAYER_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
player1.penup()
player1.goto(WIDTH/4, HEIGHT/4)

# Player 2
player2 = player1.clone()
player2.color('yellow')
player2.goto(WIDTH/4, -HEIGHT/4)

# Player 3
player3 = player1.clone()
player3.color('green')
player3.goto(-WIDTH/4, HEIGHT/4)

# Player 4
player4 = player1.clone()
player4.color('blue')
player4.goto(-WIDTH/4, -HEIGHT/4)

# Keyboard bindings
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_up, player1), 'i')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_down, player1), 'k')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_right, player1), 'l')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_left, player1), 'j')

screen.onkeypress(partial(player_up, player2), 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_down, player2), 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_right, player2), 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_left, player2), 'Left')

screen.onkeypress(partial(player_up, player3), 'w')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_down, player3), 's')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_right, player3), 'd')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_left, player3), 'a')

screen.onkeypress(partial(player_up, player4), 't')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_down, player4), 'g')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_right, player4), 'h')
screen.onkeypress(partial(player_left, player4), 'f')

screen.listen()

# Main loop that keeps window running
while True:
    # boundary checking top right
    if player1.xcor() > WIDTH/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player1.setx(WIDTH/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2)
    elif player1.xcor() < PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player1.setx(PLAYER_SIZE/2)

    if player1.ycor() > HEIGHT/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player1.sety(HEIGHT/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2)
    elif player1.ycor() < PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player1.sety(PLAYER_SIZE/2)

    # boundary checking bottom right
    if player2.xcor() > WIDTH/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player2.setx(WIDTH/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2)
    elif player2.xcor() < PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player2.setx(PLAYER_SIZE/2)

    if player2.ycor() > -PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player2.sety(-PLAYER_SIZE/2)
    elif player2.ycor() < PLAYER_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2:
        player2.sety(PLAYER_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2)

    # boundary checking top left
    if player3.xcor() > -PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player3.setx(-PLAYER_SIZE/2)
    elif player3.xcor() < PLAYER_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2:
        player3.setx(PLAYER_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2)

    if player3.ycor() > HEIGHT/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player3.sety(HEIGHT/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2)
    elif player3.ycor() < PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player3.sety(PLAYER_SIZE/2)

    # boundary checking bottom left
    if player4.xcor() > -PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player4.setx(-PLAYER_SIZE/2)
    elif player4.xcor() < PLAYER_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2:
        player4.setx(PLAYER_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2)

    if player4.ycor() > -PLAYER_SIZE/2:
        player4.sety(-PLAYER_SIZE/2)
    elif player4.ycor() < PLAYER_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2:
        player4.sety(PLAYER_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2)

    # Ball movement
    x, y = ball.position()
    x += ball.dx
    y += ball.dy

    # Border checking for ball

    if not - (WIDTH/2 + CURSOR_SIZE/2) < x < WIDTH/2 + CURSOR_SIZE/2:
        ball.home()
        ball.dx *= choice([-1, 1])
        ball.dy *= choice([-1, 1])
        continue
    elif not - (HEIGHT/2 + CURSOR_SIZE/2) < y < HEIGHT/2 + CURSOR_SIZE/2:
        ball.home()
        ball.dx *= choice([-1, 1])
        ball.dy *= choice([-1, 1])
        continue

    ball.setposition(x, y)

    # Player and ball collisions

    # Simplistic player and ball collision logic
    for player in [player1, player2, player3, player4]:
        if isCollision(ball, player):
            p_x, p_y = player.position()

            if abs(p_x - x) > abs(p_y - y):
                ball.dx *= -1
            else:
                ball.dy *= -1
            break

    screen.update()
```

Comment: I like how the bounce motion works but there is a bug i'm not sure how to fix. When you move the player while the ball is about to collide into it, the ball just goes through the player and it gets stuck in there until you move it around. I've tried messing around with the equation in the #player and ball collision part but it doesn't seem to work.